# Strange unsigned long long int behavior

Tags: c++, unsigned-long-long-int

I was using unsigned long long int for some calculations but

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << 900000000000001i64+4*pow(10, 16);
```

Gives Output:`40900000000000000`

and this

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << 900000000000011i64+4*pow(10, 16);
```

Gives Output:`40900000000000008`

Now i have no idea what is happening i tried removing `i64` tries printing `4*pow(10, 16)` gives the correct result `40000000000000000` also tried printing `40900000000000011` directly, it prints the correct result. It works fine for power of 10^14 but after that it starts to behave strangely.

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Hint: `pow` is not returning a long long int.

Comment: but when i print 4*pow(10, 16) i get the correct output

Comment: This isn't the problem, but use 'LL' to mark 'long long' constants. That `i64` stuff is some compiler's made-up thing; it's not portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you get this awkward result is because of loosing the values of the least significant bits in `double` type. `double` mantissa can only hold about 15 decimal digits and exactly 52 binary digits ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

`900000000000001i64+4*pow(10, 16)` will be converted to double trimming all lower bits. In you case there are 3 of them.

Example:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(30);
std::cout << 900000000000001i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000002i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000003i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000004i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000005i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000006i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000007i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000008i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
std::cout << 900000000000009i64 + 4 * pow(10, 16) << endl;
```

will produce result:

```
40900000000000000
40900000000000000
40900000000000000
40900000000000000
40900000000000008
40900000000000008
40900000000000008
40900000000000008
40900000000000008
40090000000000008
```

Notice how the values are **rounded** to 2<sup>3</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code (notice the explicit type conversion there).

```
typedef unsigned long long ULONG64; //Not a must, but just for code clarity

std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << 900000000000001i64 + (ULONG64)(4 * pow(10, 16));
//output -> 40900000000000001
std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << 900000000000011i64 + (ULONG64)(4 * pow(10, 16));
//output -> 40900000000000011
```

You have to tell compiler to do explicit type conversion (to ULONG64) on result returned by pow(...) function which is of type double.